# Private vector in class

Tags: c++, vector

```
    class MyStrValArray
{
private:
    vector<char> p;
public:
    void init(const int n);
    void clear();
    unsigned capacity();
    unsigned size();
};
```

I want to have a vector as private class member, and in the public part, I want to declare the size(const int n) of the vector. Is there a way to do this? 
And the reason I want to use vector is, I need to get the size / capacity of the memory, resize, or remove the nth element of the memory. Is it right to use vector in this case?

Comment: what is exactly your question ? to implement the methods ?

Comment: How can I declare the size of the vector in the public part of the class?

Comment: to change the size use `p.resize(<size>)`, to reverse a size use `p.reserve(<size>)`

Comment: I think you are trying to reimplement `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement custom string implementation then ,having "char * data" is more appropriate.

Otherwise you can use vector like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyStrValArray
{
private:
    vector<char> p;
public:
    MyStrValArray() {}
    MyStrValArray(const int sz ) : p(sz){}
    void init(const int n)
    {
        p.resize(n);
    }
    void clear()
    {
        p.clear();
    }
    unsigned capacity()
    {
        return p.capacity();
    }
    unsigned size()
    {
        return p.size();
    }


};

int main()
{
    MyStrValArray ma;
    ma.init(4);

    std::cout<<ma.size()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```